# Installing the Poppler Gem and getting bundler errors when running the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, poppler

I have added and bundled these gems but I keep getting a bundler error
cannot load such file -- gobject_introspection.so (LoadError)

`ruby
gem 'poppler', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.7'
gem "cairo", github: "rcairo/rcairo"
gem "gtk3", github: "ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also include the gems for [glib2](https://rubygems.org/gems/glib2) and [gobject-introspection](https://rubygems.org/gems/gobject-introspection) .